# Can't parse value from CSV to Double

Tags: java, csv, numberformatexception

My problem is to parse value from CSV to double. I can't understand why I can parse all values from columns A-BJ and when I have column BK java throw error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,69E+12"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at Compare.normalizacja_dziesietna(Compare.java:68)
at Compare.main(Compare.java:138)
```

For example in columnt BE there is also o big number and there is no problem with parsing...

Here there is a screenshot of the file https://pasteboard.co/HVkMt4L.png

Comment: Can you show us the java code?

Comment: It's treating the value as a String so you're trying to parse "4,96E+12" as a Double which isn't valid. Make sure the column is formatted as a number and check the value of the raw CSV file in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

`Double.parseDouble` expects `4.69E+12` instead of `4,69E+12`.

Example:

```
Double.parseDouble("4,69E+12".replaceAll(",", "\\."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use BigDecimal instead.

Read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)